# How to use capitalize() method in inputField in visualforcepage?

Tags: apex, string, inputfield

I am trying to make first letter caps using inputField in Visualforce page. I tried with below code:
created string and assigned to Inputfield.

```
                    <apex:inputField value="{!string1}"/>

string1=object.name;

string1=string1.capitalize();
```

But it is **showingError:**

> Could not resolve the entity from  value binding
>   '{!lastname}'.   can only be used with SObjects, or
>   objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You've not binded field properly to your `inputField`. `inputField` must be bind with object.
From documentation:

> `<apex:inputField`: This tag helps to display fields of any standard or custom object (Any Sales force Object) on the visualforce page. The  component respects the attributes of the associated field, including whether the field is required or unique, and the user interface widget to display to get input from the user. For example, if the specified < apex:inputField > component is a date field, a calendar input widget is displayed. The above behaviour is shown only when the tag is used inside a pageblocksection component.

Example:

```
<apex:inputField value = "{!object.Field}"/>
```

If you're using any String variable then better to use `inputText`.

```
<apex:inputText value = "{!lastname}"/>
```